# How to apply round to two pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to round the values in one column of a pandas dataframe to the decimal place specified in another column as shown in the below code.

```
    df = pandas.DataFrame({
        'price': [14.5732, 145.731, 145.722, 145.021],
        'decimal': [4, 3, 2, 2]
    })
    df['price'] = df.apply(lambda x: round(x.price, x.decimal), axis=1)
```

However, doing so leads to the following error:

```
>   df['price'] = df.apply(lambda x: round(x.price, x.decimal), axis=1)
E   TypeError: ('integer argument expected, got float', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Documentation makes it seem like round expects a float at index 0, but it is clearly not happy. Changing price to an int fixes the error, but that ruins the point of the code itself.

Comment: `[round(x, y) for x, y in zip(df['price'], df['decimal'])]`.  Should be faster than `apply` anyways.

Comment: The reason that your attempt fails is that `decimal` is getting coerced to a float.  Try `df.apply(lambda x: x, axis=1)` if you want to verify this.

Comment: I work with very large datasets though, such that memory usage is more important than speed. Won't the zip create a large, intermediate object?

Comment: No, it's lazily evaluated.

Comment: try using `round(x.price, int(x.decimal))` in apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been a pain point in pandas for a [*loooong* time](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11617).  When accessing single rows, or calling apply along the first axis, dtype coercion happens on a fairly regular basis.  The error message is confusing because it's obvious that the dtype of your decimal series is an integer type, so it should be accepted by the `round` method, but the coercion is happening behind the scenes.

You can check this with both `iloc` and `apply`:

```
>>> df.iloc[0]
price      14.5732
decimal     4.0000
Name: 0, dtype: float64

>>> df.apply(lambda x: x, axis=1)
      price  decimal
0   14.5732      4.0
1  145.7310      3.0
2  145.7220      2.0
3  145.0210      2.0
```

What's even more frustrating is that if you have an object dtype column, nothing is coerced, so the behavior isn't all that easy to predict!

```
>>> df['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> df.iloc[0]
price      14.5732
decimal          4
foo            bar
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

---

Long story short, it's confusing and not intuitive at all.  A couple workarounds are casting the decimal in the lambda function or using a list comprehension (probably faster than apply).

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: round(x.price, int(x.decimal)), axis=1)
0     14.5732
1    145.7310
2    145.7200
3    145.0200
dtype: float64

>>> [round(x, y) for x, y in zip(df['price'], df['decimal'])]
[14.5732, 145.731, 145.72, 145.02]
```

Note the representation will not change when shown in a series, but the value will have been rounded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generator like so:

```
>>> gen = (i for i in df.decimal)
>>> df.price = df.price.apply(lambda x: round(x, next(gen))) 
>>> df
      price  decimal
0   14.5732        4
1  145.7310        3
2  145.7200        2
3  145.0200        2
```

Comment: Why not use `[ ]` for column access?

Comment: @AMC Didn't want to press more keys

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
df['price'] = df.apply(lambda x: round(x.price, int(x.decimal)), axis=1)
```